# Get Url of List, with all items

Tags: 2010, list

I created a document library by code, and I need to return the URL of the All Items page.

I tried this, but its not what I am looking for

```
 SPList oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists.TryGetList(DocumentLibraryName);
                        if (oSPList == null)
                        {
                            Guid ID = oSPWeb.Lists.Add(DocumentLibraryName, DocumentLibraryName + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                            oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists[ID];
                            DocumentLibraryLink = oSPList.DefaultViewUrl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the complete url to the Default view and not just the server relative url to the view.  If that is true, you can do the following to get the easily get the full url.

```
DocumentLibraryLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(oSPWeb.Url, oSPList.DefaultView.Url);
```

The result is something like this

```
http://servername/sitecollection/site/lists/listname/defaultpagename.aspx
```

If the view is not the default view, you can use this.  ViewName is the Display Name for the view.

```
DocumentLibraryLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(oSPWeb.Url, oSPList.Views[ViewName].Url);
```

This will give the url even if it is located in the FORMS folder.

```
http://servername/sitecollection/site/lists/listname/forms/viewname.aspx
```

Comment: efaultviewurl is dispform.aspx, I need the link to /Forms/Allitems.aspx. but I dont want to hardcode i

Comment: so is allitems the default view for this list?

Comment: yes its always the default view.

Comment: this should work?    DocumentLibraryLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(oSPWeb.Url, oSPList.Views["All Documents"].Url);

Comment: That worked for me in quick mock test on my development instance using an OOB document library.  Also, if it is always the default view then DefaultView.Url returns the correct url in SP2010.  this is a different property than DefaultViewUrl which returns the server relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oSPWeb.Site.Url,oSPList.DefaultViewUrl);
```

Comment: defaultviewurl is dispform.aspx, I need the link to /Forms/Allitems.aspx. but I dont want to hardcode i.

Comment: That is strange I get /Forms/Allitems.aspx using that code