# Create a link to a library from within a page

Tags: web-part, hyperlink, top-link-bar, links-list

is it possible to create a link on a page to a library within the same page. So for example, I have a small list of 8 categories on my page, when i click on the first category "Governance" I would like to be taken to the Governance web part (library) on the same page. 
Am I making my self clear?
thanks,
Colin

Comment: Are you talking about [Anchor tags as Bookmarks](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a  [relative url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and), so if it's a list you do this:

```
Lists/MyList
```

or if it's a library:

```
mylibrary/
```

This is the simple solution, and will only work if you are located on the "top" of your *SPWeb*.  If your question was about codebehind (C#) then the [URL can be resolved](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/32123/627).
The URL can also be resolved with Client Object Model in JavaScript, like this:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var site = ctx.get_site();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('UrlTest');
ctx.load(list);
ctx.load(site);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {a=site
  console.log(site.get_url(), list.get_defaultViewUrl());
});
```

here *site* is not necessary, as `list.get_defaultViewUrl()` will return a *root* relative URL (starting from `/`), but I decided to add it to show how to get absolute URL.

Comment: it is mylibrary/ , however, I am developing the front end and am not a programmer. So perhaps this is too deep for me. I am trying to build a Table of Contents for my Library parts on the same site page. So when they click on Chapter 1, it will take them to the Library, or book mark.

Comment: So adding a link manually in a content editor web part or similar should do the trick?